# Compute $P\left( Y \leq 0, X = 0 \right)$ with $X$ and $Y$ having medians zero.

Tags: probability, statistics

For a bivariate density $f(x,y)$ defined on the real line, I have been trying to compute

> $$ \int_{-\infty}^0 f\left(0,y \right) dy $$

where it is known that $X$ and $Y$ have medians equal to zero but are not necessarily symmetric about them. Can the integral be simplified based on that information? Perhaps it is more helpful to think of the integral as

$$P\left( Y \leq 0 | X = 0 \right) P\left( X = 0 \right)$$

but either way I do not see how to evaluate this without making further assumptions. I have been stuck here for some time so all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your expression in integral is not correct.

$$P(X=0, Y\geq 0) = \int_{\Bbb R^2} {\Bbb 1}_{\{x=0, y\geq 0\}}(x,y) f(x,y) dxdy $$

$$=\int_{\Bbb R^2} {\Bbb 1}_{\{x=0\}} (x) 1_{\{ y\geq 0\}}(y) f(x,y) dxdy $$

$$ = \int_0^\infty \int_0^0 f(x,y) dx dy $$

$$= 0$$

The idea is that the set $\{x=0, y\geq 0\}$ (an half line) has zero measure, so if you integrate a function over it, it gives you 0

Comment: The integral is definitely nonzero. Consider for instance a bivariate normal distribution, put $X=0$ and integrate over $Y$.

Comment: @JohnK : And what you proppose does **not** calculate $P(X=0, Y \in A)$. Are you sure you're not mistaken with $P(Y\geq 0 | X=0)$ that is indeed not 0 (but a totally different thing)

Comment: I think I see the confusion. Don't interpret the $X=0$ literally. Just consider $0<X<\epsilon$ instead for some small $\epsilon$.

Comment: @JohnK : then $P(0 < X<\epsilon, Y\geq 0) = \int_0^{\epsilon} \int_0^\infty f(x,y) dy dx$, but you I don't think you can say much (are your $X$ and $Y$ independant?) PS : things in maths must be taken litterally, or you're sure to crash somewhere ^^

Comment: No, nothing else is known unfortunately.

Comment: @JohnK : then "everything" is possible, from $0$ to $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Thanks a lot, it appears then that this is as far as I can go.